# django - permission problem when uploading a file

Tags: python, django, forms, file-upload

I'm working on creating a form with which the user can upload an image and I get this error:

```
[Errno 13] Permission denied:
```

Can someone provide some guidance on what I would need to change (keeping in mind I'm running the development server on windows) for it to work?  Is it something in settings.py or do I need to change the permissions of the directory that files are uploaded to?

Comment: I'd bet on directory permissions. You can either change upload destination, or change permissions on current destination folder...

Comment: @sq1020: Please **update** the question to include the results of an `ls -l` on the upload directory so that we can see the permissions and ownership.

Answer (score 0):

`[Errno 13] Permission denied` is a [Python OSError](https://docs.python.org/2/library/exceptions.html#exceptions.OSError):

> It is raised when a function returns a system-related error (not for illegal argument types or other incidental errors).

The number 13 means `Permission denied`, the user who launch your app doesn't have access in write to the folder where you want to upload.